# Django + Axios: File download not working in Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, download, vuejs2, axios

I am using Axios to send my Django backend information, which in turns creates a file and sends it back to the front end.  The code I have below works great in Safari and Chrome.  However, the file does not download in firefox.  BTW, no errors show up in the firefox console, or in Django.

Axios

```
axios({
  method:'post',
  url:'/api/downloadDoc',
  responseType:'blob',
  data: params,
})
.then(response => {
  let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/force-download'})
  let link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  link.download = "YourPaper.docx"
  link.click()

})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Django View Sending File

```
def downloadPaper(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        #Recieve info through post and create document
        #variable path is path to newly created document

        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(path, 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + 'yourpaper.docx'
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path)

        return response

    return HttpResponse(status=405)
```

I am hoping someone knows what could be causing firefox to not download.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fetch("/api/admin/plugin/download/" + id , {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: new Headers({
            "Authorization": this.token,
            "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"
          }),
        }).then(response => {
          response.blob().then(blob => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            // must add <a> to body, then it works
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = decodeURI(response.headers.get("filename"));
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
          });
        })`

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to go along with the code?